# Multiple custom serializers for same entity in Spring Boot

Tags: json, serialization, spring-boot, jackson, json-serialization

I'm working on a Spring Boot application. I've created a custom serializer for one entity A and registered it using @JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class) annotation. Whenever i send A in ResponseEntity<> the custom serializer is called and everything is working fine till this point.

Now there is another API in which i need to send a Collection of A in response. But i cant use same serializer to construct the list of A's as response parameters are totally different. I need to write one more serializer for same entity .

How can i configure 2 serializers for same entity? They should be called based on the object type sent in response i.e. When i'm sending A, then serializer1 should be called and when i'm sending Collection, the serializer2 should be called.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

A simple workaround would be to annotate the collection to use a specific serializer for content. E.g.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomSerializer.class)
class A {
}

class AList {
    @JsonSerialize(contentUsing = AnotherCustomSerializer.class)
    private final List<A> list;
}
```